# Displaying the model's__unicode__ in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to display the model's username in Django Admin interface but not very sure how to do it..

```
The models.py:

    class Adult(models.Model):    
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                    blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username

Admin.py:

    class AdultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('??', 'Student_Name',)
        search_fields = ['??',]

    admin.site.register(Adult, AdultAdmin)
```

What should go inside the ?? above ? I would like to display the unicode or the self.user.username? How do i do it? Need some guidance...

Comment: Add `__unicode__`, and `Student_Name` is not part of that model; unless you didn't include it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the [`list_display` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) there are four things you can add there:

1. A field
2. Some method (a callable) that accepts one variable that is the instance for which the row is being displayed.
3. A string that is the name of a method or attribute defined in the model class.
4. A string that is the name of a method that is defined in `ModelAdmin`.

For your case we need #3 for `list_display`.

For [`search_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) its easier as you can use follow notation (`__`) to do lookups.

In the end we come up with this:

```
class AdultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'Student_Name',)
    search_fields = ['user__username']
```

Comment: a question: must both __unicode__ and user_username be used together at the same time to be effective?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, because one is for searching and the other controls what attributes are shown in the list view.

Comment: also you can add after --unicode-- method declaration: --unicode--.short_description = 'student name'

Comment: Ok, what if the unicode is some arbitrary function. How can you search the '\_\_unicode__' or '\_\_str__' field without getting `Cannot resolve keyword u''`

Comment: Generally this would be `__str__` for python3-based projects.